# How can I make python open a cmd and set : cd and then command that I need to use

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, automation, subprocess

I want to make script that will open and pre set cmd with scrcpy commands.
I tried modules like os,subprocess,pyautogui
When I tried to open cmd with os and type inside it with pyautogui it didnt work
What should I use to type commands.
All I need to write is 'cd "directory"' and scrcpy but I cant find a way to do it with python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
import os
os.system('cmd /c "Your Command Prompt Command"')
```

Comment: If you indent your code with 4 spaces it will recognize it and apply syntax highlighting. Also make sure you're actually answering the questioners answer, because he also wants to execute additional commands.

Comment: This helped to get to the needed dir

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to do it

```swift
import os as os
os.startfile("cmd.exe")
```

And to run the command use

```swift
os.system("Your Command")
```

This will show the command you passed into the cmd terminal.